# How to show multiple images in blade in Laravel from Amazon S3 storage?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I have `Book` model and there is a field called `cover`, where I save image link.

I want to get images' links from S3 storage in `Collection` of Book.
How can I do it?

Comment: Let me get this right you already uploaded the books to S3 by the standalone aws uploading system right? Now you want to get the link of the cover of each book  you have stored in S3 and save it to DB to the Field 'cover' right?

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide details on your front-end, I assume you're using blade for it.

To get the images of all the books inside the collection and show them in the front-end, you should do it something like this:

(YourController.php)

```
public function collection(User $user){
   $collection = Collection::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
   $books = $collection->books;
   return view('collection', compact('collection', 'books'));
}
```

In your view, you'd like to `foreach` each book.

```
@foreach($books as $book)
    <img src="{{Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl('directoryWhereYouStoredYourFiles/' . $book->featured_image, now()->addMinutes(30))}}" alt="cover">
@endforeach
```